# how to pass a single value parameter through jndi in glassfish server?

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, jndi

Hi i would like to set context level parameter through JNDI but i am getting problem with Glasfish server when i am manually set the parameter like the below in web.xml
 < env-entry>
< env-entry-name>name< /env-entry-name>
< env-entry-value>value< /env-entry-value>
< env-entry-type>type< /env-entry-type>
< /env-entry>

 while i am setting the above patameters on web.xml it gives error like 
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'env-entry-type'. One of 
 '{http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee:mapped-name, 
i am acquiring the initialContext object by this object i got the environment context on java:/comp/env/  
 now can any one help me how to set single value parameter using JNDI glass fish server in eclipse?

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the order of the elements. The correct order is:

```
<env-entry>
   <env-entry-name>name</env-entry-name>
   <env-entry-type>type</env-entry-type>
   <env-entry-value>value</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```